# Appium Espresso backdoor

Tags: android, automation, appium, android-espresso

I use Espresso to call the method

AndroidDriver androidDriver = this.powerWebDriver().getAndroidWebDriver();
"androidDriver.executeScript("mobile: backdoor", scriptArgss);"

and I got this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unknown mobile command "backdoor". Only shell,scrollBackTo,viewportScreenshot,deepLink,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast,acceptAlert,dismissAlert,batteryInfo,deviceInfo,changePermissions,getPermissions,performEditorAction commands are supported.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What should this command do? That command is not supported, as the error-message is saying.

Comment: I get the same error too. It looks like the espresso driver is not included in the project. Waiting for a solution too...